# Accuracy assessment in QGIS

Tags: qgis, accuracy

I am using QGIS and the SCP plug-in to classify a sentinel 2 image.

As for the reference shapefile my point layer, is a vector point layer containing the names of crops, which were used in creating ROIs.

My question is: 
Do I need to alter this crop point file file further in order to generate a valid accuracy assessment? I am aware it needs to be converted into either a shapefile or raster, but
Do I need to attach the pixel values from the ground truth image to the crops, in order to use this as a reference layer?

I have computed accuracy assessments already but they are between 0.02 and 4%.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this thread when looking for the same problem.